# Commit failed in Eclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse

I am trying to commit one java file in Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 using SVN

When I do Team/Commit on the file I get the following.

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File 'C:\Users\...\workspace\...\src\com\MyCode.java' is out of date
```

When I try and do Team/Update - whether on the file or the folder or the project, I get

```
Some resources were not updated.
svn: E175002: chunked stream ended unexpectedly
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/project/!svn/vcc/default'
```

I have tried

1. Restarting Visual SVN Server
2. Deleting the .java file and then adding it again
3. Renaming the .java file, and then renaming it back
4. Updating the Eclipse and SVN software, and trying again
5. Team/Revert, Team/Update, making changes, Team/Commit

Can anyone help? (all other files/folders etc. work fine)